# Adapt random image placement code for flexible layout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for an effect very similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/G5Xrz/

```
function rnd(max) { return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max+1)) }

function showImage(container, maxwidth, maxheight, imgsrc, imgwidth, imgheight) {
var id = "newimage" + rnd(1000000);
$(container).append(
    "<img id='" + id + "' src='" + imgsrc + 
    "' style='display:block; float:left; position:absolute;" + 
    "left:" + rnd(maxwidth - imgwidth) + "px;" +
    "top:"  + rnd(maxheight - imgheight) + "px'>");
$('#' + id).fadeIn();
return id;
}

setInterval(
function() {
    showImage("#container", 400, 600, 
              "http://placekitten.com/" + (90 + rnd(10)) + "/" + (90 + rnd(10)), 
              100, 100);
}, 700);
```

But i'd prefer a flexible layout, ie images not bound by a div with predefined height and width, instead responding to the dimensions of the browser.

The following piece of code seems to have a more appropriate way of generating the random positions:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/15/

```
function makeNewPosition(){

// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $(window).height() - 50;
var w = $(window).width() - 50;

var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(){
var newq = makeNewPosition();
var oldq = $('.a').offset();
var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

$('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
  animateDiv();        
});

};
```

However I'm very much a beginner with javascript and I don't know how to combine the two.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: So are you trying to place images or animate an element within the browser window? Please explain some more

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to place multiple images randomly and indefinitely. I've no interest in the animation from the second bit of code, only the method of generating the random position based on the browser dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this part from the second code:

```
// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $(window).height() - 50;
var w = $(window).width() - 50;
```

and use those variables `h` and `w` with the browser height and width (minus 50) as the appropriate parameters in this part of the first code:

```
setInterval(
function() {
    showImage("#container", 400, 600, 
              "http://placekitten.com/" + (90 + rnd(10)) + "/" + (90 + rnd(10)), 
              100, 100);
}, 700);
```

Also, the first code has this HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width:400px; height:600px; background: green; position:relative"></div>
```

That hard-codes the height and width at pixel values. You can use a CSS percentage value to make the width respond to the parent container's size. However, you will need JS to set the height properly; a percentage for the height does nothing

Putting that all together (and removing the "minus 50" part), you get this:

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/mQXjm/)**

```html
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100px; background: green; position:relative"></div>
```

```js
function adjustContainerHeight(height) {
    $('#container').height(height);
}

adjustContainerHeight($(window).height());

setInterval(
    function() {
        var h = $(window).height();
        var w = $(window).width();
        adjustContainerHeight(h);
        showImage("#container", w, h, 
                  "http://placekitten.com/" + (90 + rnd(10)) + "/" + (90 + rnd(10)), 
                  100, 100);
    }, 700);
```

This updates the height of the container when the page is first loaded, and once again whenever the random image is placed. More robust code would have a separate height-adjusting event handler that updates the height whenever the page size changes.

Comment: Thanks Rory. Exactly what I needed, and thank for the clear explanation!